# .htaccess rules for Laravel installation

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I am having trouble getting my Laravel installation to work on my local server. It has been pulled from a server where it was working correctly but now none of the links work and I can't seem t get them working.

My WAMP Laravel installation is in the folder WWW (root folder of local server)...

Here is the /htaccesss (as it comes from the live server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /~celeb/index.php [L]
```

Now, I know I will have to remove the '~celeb' part in the Rewrite Rule but when I do this the links still do not work. For example, when I click on a link such as "****/signup" it doesn't work, but when I add 'index.php' into it ("*****/index.php/signup') it works fine. 
Does anyone know why this is happening as it is driving me crazy!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and adding the RewriteBase rule to the .htaccess file did solve it.

Example for url : localhost/example/index.php :

```
RewriteBase /example
```

Then restart apache and maybe it'll work :)

Bests,
Kevin